# Not a legal ole auth date issue while writing to datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I have developed a web application to import Excel data into a SQL Server table using bulk copy column mapping. I used a `select * from sheet` query to copy the sheet data and insert into data table before writing it to table.

There are 20 columns in the sheet. The last column contains data of type datetime, string, integers and special characters. Its a mixed data type. When the application tried to copy and insert data into data table means it shows

> Not a legal ole auth date

I have checked the last column values. Date value is correct only but it shows not a legal ole auth date issue.

Instead of using `select * from sheet`, is there any alternative approach like insert data into data table from Excel by row wise using for loop ?

Code is

```
OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", excelSheets[0]);

using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection1))
{
    dataAdapter.Fill(dt); **// issue raise when it try to fill the datatable**
}
```

Comment: I know the issue is in the data. If we insert the data row wise means we will get the actual bad data in the column . Then it will be easy to convert the date.

Comment: are you explicitly defining the column types?

Comment: Also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver15